# Shopware 6 get cart in page

Tags: shopware, shopware6

i want to get the current cart when the product page is loaded.

```php
public function onProductPageLoadedEvent(ProductPageLoadedEvent $event) {
    $cart = ... get cart here
}
```

i have implemented the CartService already, but i need a token.

Answer (score 1):

The token is part of the SalesChannelContext. You can get the customer's cart like this:

```
public function onProductPageLoadedEvent(ProductPageLoadedEvent $event) {
    $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($event->getSalesChannelContext()->getToken(), $event->getSalesChannelContext());
}
```